# How to use one HttpClient per application?

Tags: android, apache, http, httpclient

I am looking for an efficient way to use the `HttpClient` for my android application.
I use HttpClients inside different activities and I want use just one client for the application and pass it around the activities. Even though I look through some answers I couldn't figure out a way to use just one client for my several activities.

Can you please explain me how to implement this pattern possibly with a sample code?

Thank you.

Comment: HttpClient is a lightweight object that you can create at will and dispose of when done with. What benefit are you gaining from re-architecting your code to avoid creating multiple instances of it?

Comment: Apache's site says it differently: http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/performance.html

Generally it is recommended to have a single instance of HttpClient per communication component or even per application.

Comment: Hmmm, I stand corrected then. Personally, I have never had a problem with using dedicated HttpClient instances, even with 1000's of concurrent user. But I won't disagree with the official documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few things that you need to keep in mind before implementing such a HttpClient.

1. A single instance of the client can be achieved by using a Singleton Pattern.
2. Make sure you are using a Thread to do all your downloading in the background and dont use the UI Thread.
3. Maintain a queue for all the download requests. A single Activity could have multiple requests to download various components such as, data, images, etc before it can be populated. All these requests need to be queued and run one after the other.
4. Incase you switch an Activity before the HttpClient queue is clear, the queue should be cleared so that it does not stall the loading of your components of the new activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I guess singleton pattern will be useful for me should I have a class called something like `SingletonClient` and how one `DefaultHttpClient` field in it? Am I correct? and call `getInstance()` whenever I want a client?

Comment: Yes the Singleton class would be a sort of a wrapper inside which there would be a single DefaultHttpClient. You need to provide a few functions to set some of the basic paramters of the http client, also the types of request [GET,POST] etc.

Comment: Should I do something like this: https://gist.github.com/2398657
but then if I call `getInstance()` doesn't it initialize the client every time it's called so the same thing happens as before? I guess I couldn't grasp the idea well. Can you help me?

Comment: Well in this case everytime a new DefaultHttpClient is being created. Check this link http://www.shubhayu.com/android/witer-a-simple-httpmanager-with-the-apache-http-client I have implemented a simple HttpClient which is a single instance in the app, however I have not implemented the queuing of multiple requests. This might help you start.

Comment: @Shubhayu +1, Do you have suggestions/idea in relation to your queuing thing?

Comment: The requests should be separate entities in object form. You should have a list (concurrent) where these objects are queued. The httpClient should pick objects from this list and process. In that case, clearing the queue is just a call to clear().

Answer (score 0):

A dependency injection framework is typically used for this kind of scenario

https://www.raywenderlich.com/171327/dependency-injection-android-dagger-2

Comment: Isn't there any other option without dependency injection?