# Not able to implement singleton across multiple activities

Tags: android, singleton

I am using class `SIHttpClient` to implement singleton on maintaining single instance of `DefaultHttpClient`. I am doing this because, as I have [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10174004/how-to-use-one-httpclient-per-application) that maintaining single instance of DefaultHttpClient will help me in keeping session persistent with PHP at backend.

```
public class SIHttpClient {
   private static SIHttpClient instance = null;
   private DefaultHttpClient client;
   private SIHttpClient() {
        this.client=new DefaultHttpClient();
   }
   public static SIHttpClient getInstance() {
      if(instance == null) {
         instance = new SIHttpClient();
      }
      return instance;
   }
   public SIResponse makePostRequest(String url,RequestObject request){
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair(request.getParam(), request.getValue()));
        try {
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
          //error handling
        }
        try {
            HttpResponse response = this.client.execute(httpPost);
            //some parsing done to convert to SIResponse
            return new SIResponse().httpResponseToSIResponse(response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //exception handling
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling
        }
   }

   public SIResponse makePostRequest(String url){
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        try {
            HttpResponse response = this.client.execute(httpPost);
            //some parsing done to convert to SIResponse
            return new SIResponse().httpResponseToSIResponse(response);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            //exception handling
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //exception handling
        }
   }
}
```

> ```
> LoginActivity
> ```

```
    public class LoginActivity() extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        //setting request oject from some EditTextViews
        RequestObject request=new RequestObject("username","password")

        //set onclick listener code to login
        new UserLoginTask().execute(request);
        //
    }
    //
    private class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask<RequestObject, Void, SIResponse> { 
        SIHttpClient httpClient=SIHttpClient.getInstance();
        protected Long doInBackground(RequestObject... request) {       
            //request to fetch user data 
            return httpClient.makePostRequest("http://www.example.com/login", request[0]);                     
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(SIResponse result) {
           if(result.getStatus()){
            //got to HomeActivity
           }
           else{
            //display erros
           }
        }
    }
}
```

> HomeActivity

```
public class HomeActivity() extends Activity{

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        new FetchUserDataTask().execute();
    }
    //
    private class FetchUserDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, SIResponse> { 
        SIHttpClient httpClient=SIHttpClient.getInstance();
        protected Long doInBackground() {       
            //request to fetch user data 
            return httpClient.makePostRequest("http://www.example.com/fetchUser");                     
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(SIResponse result) {
           if(result.getStatus()){
            //populate views with returned data
           }
           else{
            //display erros
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Now problem that I am facing,forget about persistent sessions I am even not able to implement Singleton for `SIHttpClient` every time I call `getInstance` It creates new instance, which I concluded through debugger. What I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Partly, you are not using double-checked locking, and so you could wind up with multiple instances if `getInstance()` is called multiple times simultaneously across multiple threads. Beyond that, make sure that you have no `android:process` attributes in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

initialize your instance from the start:

```
private static final SIHttpClient instance = new SIHttpClient();
```

Then return that instance:

```
  public static SIHttpClient getInstance() {

  return instance;
```

}

Comment: He's using lazy initialization, you're using eager. How does this fix the issue at hand? Could you expand on how this solves it?

Comment: Jeroen, I'm guessing that you can explain it much better than me. If he initializes instance to equal null, then it is always going to null when he calls getInstance. With eager initialization, you can make it final so that instance will persist. Lazy evaluation is better suited for when you are likely to have more than one instance of your class.  For a singleton, strict enforcement is better.

Comment: To the contrary, I'm not really convinced this is the solution. Why would it return `null` in this particular situation? Eager and lazy are two approaches, but they should both yield a singleton as result.

Comment: So what is your solution?

Comment: I don't have one, otherwise I would've posted it. It is not a competition: we're here to help eachother. If the answer doesn't help, well, then it's not an answer.

Comment: Perhaps I should have worded my questions differently.  I was curious as to what your thoughts were.  My answer was based on my app that does something similar and works with the strict initialization.